# Setting up nsfw command for discord

Tags: javascript, discord

What I did was use code from another command which does work. The command grabs images from a link then pastes them in the chat. I have made 3 other commands which post things such as hug | kiss | bye, etc... I thought I can simply add a similar thing for **NSFW** commands but that doesn't seem to be the case. The command **partially works** the text goes through but doesn't respond with an image like other commands.

**Here are a few examples of the output for the command**

Image of the output for discord command
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Here is the code for the command that does not work**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = {
  config: {
    name: "lewd",
    aliases: [""],
    category: "nsfw",
    description: "Sends an NSFW image ;)",
    usage: `${config.PREFIX}cat`,
},
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

    const res = await fetch('https://gallery.fluxpoint.dev/api/nsfw/lewd');
    const img = (await res.json()).link;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`OwO`)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter(`Requested ${message.member.displayName}`,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
}
```

**If you need the code that does work and output an image here it is**

````
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = {
  config: {
    name: "hug",
    aliases: [""],
    category: "images",
    description: "hug",
    usage: `${config.PREFIX}cat`,
},
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

    const res = await fetch('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/hug');
    const img = (await res.json()).link;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`;)`)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter(`Requested ${message.member.displayName}`,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjIwV.png
````

Comment: `https://gallery.fluxpoint.dev/api/nsfw/lewd` = Authorization header not set

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry im new to coding but how do i do that and where do i put it in the code?